# Is the noise of op-amps and ADCs Gaussian/mean=0?

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, noise

I understand that white noise is not always Gaussian. In general, is the Vpp/Vrms noise stated in operational amplifier and ADC data sheets Gaussian/has a mean of 0? Any exemptions to be aware of while selecting an operational amplifier?

My guess for interpreting the Vpp values:  x V of noise is a Gaussian curve with values ranging from +x/2 V to -x/2 V. A 10 V of Vpp noise means that the noise is a Gaussian curve with a +5 V max value on one side of the Gaussian curve and the -5V on the other side. Can it be more than x/2 on either the positive or the negative side?

And a related question, is all thermal noise Gaussian? Eg. Skin-Electrode interface in EMG.

Comment: If the mean weren't 0 then I think it wouldn't be noise, but rather a DC signal which we might call 'offset'.

Comment: Thermal noise is Gaussian, the integral of each Poisson event. White noise isn't necessarily Gaussian. If it is, it is labeled as such. Otherwise, you don't know. Sometimes, because it is white and Gaussian, thermal noise is called "white Gaussian," memory serving. Things can be white. They can be Gaussian. But these are independent qualities. So either, or, or both, or neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noise in such amplifiers is a small signal disturbance, so we can consider the response to be linear and the noise histogram to be symmetric.

Furthermore, due to a multitude of individual physical processes constituting the noise "of the op-amp", you can infer that the histogram is gaussian due to the central limit theorem.

If you instead consider a single component, such as a Zener diode breakdown, for noise generation, the situation is less general and noise might not be gaussian.

For ADCs it depends on their resolution/speed. If the resolution is limited by analog noise, then noise is usually gaussian. This happens for very fast or high-res converters. In contrast, a slow general purpose 8-bit ADC is not limited thermally, so its noise is dominated by quantization noise, which can be rectangular for white input signals, or even can contain harmonic components fot non-white input signals.

Comment: Thank you tobalt.